# Why doesn't clojure core library support an index-of function?

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

Recently, I've been starting out with clojure programming and functional programming in general. One thing I noticed, solving some basic programming puzzles, is that there is no index-of function for vectors, eg. no reverse for the core function `nth`. I've seen people implement it themselves or use some java substitute implementation.

My question isn't as much if there's a workaround (but if you know of a particularly elegant one, share it), because I know there is. What I'm wondering is: why is this the case, eg. why did the clojure developers decide against implementing what seems like such a basic operation. Is doing a position lookup in a vector somehow non-idiomatic in clojure and would ideally be done in other ways? How?

Comment: In like 2 and a bit years of using Clojure, I've never needed such a function. What's an example of a use case that you need it for? I'd wager that you're just approaching the problem non-idiomatically. The only container that has good index access is a vector. Usually you aren't wanting to do a linear search over a list just to find an index if possible.

Comment: Current problem I'm working on is this: https://github.com/gigasquid/wonderland-clojure-katas/blob/master/card-game-war/src/card_game_war/game.clj Had a function described above existed I'd simply compare the indexes of the two cards and go for the bigger one. This way, I'm not sure what the "idiomatic" approach is. I know about .indexOf, but I want to approach the problem in a clojurish way.

Comment: I think the thought "I need an index apart from other data" in not so clojurish (data-oriented), e.g. take a look when index is a value of hash here: https://github.com/aaronj1335/wonderland-clojure-katas/blob/master/card-game-war/src/card_game_war/game.clj#L9

Comment: Besides, indexOf for a list is linear-complex every time, but build a hashmap once and query it is more constant in time ;)

Comment: Thanks. Good stuff.

Comment: Just to point out why I think it's unnecessary, [here's a solution that I wrote up that doesn't rely on using indices](https://github.com/carcigenicate/mandelbrot-redo/blob/master/src/mandelbrot_redo/irrelevant/war.clj) (maybe look at it *after* you've written your own). Instead of using indices, I'm just popping the cards in a `loop`. This is idiomatic iteration when you don't have an idea ahead of time how many iterations you'll need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There *is* a standard Clojure function that almost does what *the problem* requires.

If we look at [the skeleton source](https://github.com/gigasquid/wonderland-clojure-katas/blob/master/card-game-war/src/card_game_war/game.clj), what we need to do is invert a sequence such as ...

```
(def ranks [2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 :jack :queen :king :ace])
```

... into a map (or other function) that gives us the index of *every* value:

```
{7 5, :king 11, 4 2, :queen 10, :ace 12, 6 4, 3 1, 2 0, :jack 9, 9 7, 5 3, 10 8, 8 6}
```

We can do this *once and for all*.

The standard function that nearly does this is [`clojure.set/map-invert`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.set/map-invert).

- But it works on maps, not on sequences.
- But it treats them as sequences of pairs.

So a simple function to invert a vector (or other sequence) into an index function is ...

```
(defn indexes-of [v]
  (->> v
       (map-indexed vector)
       (clojure.set/map-invert)))
```

For example,

```
   (indexes-of ranks)
=> {7 5, :king 11, 4 2, :queen 10, :ace 12, 6 4, 3 1, 2 0, :jack 9, 9 7, 5 3, 10 8, 8 6}
```

So the folks who say that you've got the wrong end of the stick are correct. 
However, it is surely better to perform a domain-free computation like this within Clojure itself, however smoothly Clojure docks with whatever VM it happens to be running on.

What we need is a cloak to throw over a vector to make it into a map: just as [`rseq`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/rseq) throws a cloak over a vector, making it appear as a reversed sequence. Then we need not assume that `map-invert` will accept a sequence of pairs. (To be safe now, we could feed the sequence of pairs `into` a map to feed to `map-invert`).

Answer (score 3):

Answering both questions in reverse order:

**"Workaround"**: a `vector` in clojure implements `java.util.List`, so java works simple (elegant enough, imo)

```
(.indexOf [1 2 3] 2)
1
```

besides, a string can leverage `clojure.string/index-of`

**Why** not in clojure.core: this is equivalent to a question "why there's no [a polymorphic fn] for various collection types", which is answered here: https://clojure.org/guides/faq#conj and here https://gist.github.com/reborg/dc8b0c96c397a56668905e2767fd697f#why-clojure-doesnt-have-a-generic-insert-lookup-append-that-works-the-same-on-all-collections

Comment: I was under impression using Java types/functions is bad practice and should be avoided.

Comment: Not at all, clojure embraces host interop with both java and js. The only thing is - it's looking kinda ugly (it's just imho: dot, camelCase), besides, the need to write cljc conditionals for both.

Comment: @VladBokov In this case it also works the same in cljs, so no need for conditionals.

Comment: @LurzimSabahudin : if you are concerned with dotted notation, just write a wrapper around it. Many core functions are basically wrappers...and that is all.Clojurists cannot say Java is evil while Clojure itself is Java